# Find Number of Possible Alphabet Strings from Number Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, recursion

> Given a string `12345` and a alphabet to number mapping like   `a =1`, `b =2`.., `y=25`, `z=26`; write a code to find the number of possible alphabet strings from the given string.
>
> E.x. string `12345` has possible alphabet strings as `{lcde,awde, abcde}` from the mappings `{12-3-4-5, 1-23-4-5, 1-2-3-4-5}`.

I have a general idea of how to do it. I imagine it would be recursive. Look at the first digit and add it's char mapping to the result and then recurse with the sub array (1, size - 1). Also look at the two first digits and see if they are <= 26. If so, add that to the result and recurse (2, size - 2). Do this until number array is empty.

I get stuck on the actual implementation though. Is there a smarter way to do this than recursion?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: and yet the score is 2 :)

Comment: I don't get how `12345` is mapped to `lcde`. Could you explain the system? Perhaps, in explaining the system in a clear way, you will not only enable others to tell you how to do this, but may also enlighten yourself. ;-)

Comment: l = 12, c = 3, d = 4, e =5

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to **Word Break Problem**. You can use same approach to solve it .you can use memoization to reduce overall running time. If you see in your given example:

```
12-3-4-5, 1-23-4-5, 1-2-3-4-5
```

4 and 5 is getting repeated and you are calculating it again and again. You can store permutation of given index first time you calculated and use it later whenever you visit same index.

**pseudo code:**

```
recursive_function(string,index)
 if you have already calculated values for this index in previous call
    return value

 recursive_function(string,index+1)
 if possible 
   recursive_function(string,index+2) 

 store this value for future use.
```

**Detail:**

when you have recursive call for say index `i` ,when you are done with this call (basically returning from current recursion) you have already used/calculated/found all possible values (all permutation for sub-string starting at index `i`). you can store these values because if you will see there may be times when you will come again to index `i` from some other index say`j (j<i)`. so now this time you can return from this place itself instead of more recursive call for index `i` as you have already calculated values for index `i` and that will be same irrespective of `j`

Comment: not sure what you mean by "calculate for all possible at current index"

Comment: @saleeeeen see my update. i have added details. I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

Just finish this coding, idea is from @dream_machine

Basically, it's a backtracking algorithm, complexity is O(2n!), 
Need keep tracking the `left` to know should put string to output.

Seems the algorithm is too slow, maybe need add some memo to speed it up.

```
 void helper(int start, string &s, string &path, vector<string> &result, int);

vector<string>
getPossibleCombo(string &s) {
    vector<string> result;
    string path;
    helper(0, s, path, result, s.size());
    return result;
}

void helper(int start, string &s, string &path, vector<string> &result, int left) {
    if (start == s.size() && left == 0) {
        result.push_back(path);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = start; i < s.size(); i++) {
        path.push_back('a' + (s[i] - '0') - 1);
        helper(i + 1, s, path, result, left - 1);
        path.pop_back();

        if (i < s.size() - 1 && s[i] > '0' && s[i] <= '2') { // can try two.
            if (s[i] == '2' && s[i+1] > '6')
                continue;
            int c = (s[i] - '0') * 10 + s[i + 1] - '0';
            path.push_back('a' + c - 1);
            helper(i + 2, s, path, result, left - 2);
            path.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    string s("12345");
    auto r = getPossibleCombo(s);
    for (auto &s : r) {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

output is

```
bash-3.2$ g++ -std=c++11 -g test2.cpp && ./a.out
abcde
awde
lcde
```